# Qt : How to add a widget to right of QStatusBar

Tags: qt

When I add new widget to status bar using `addWidget` function of `QStatusBar` class this new widget will be added to the left of the status bar but I'm going to add it to the right. Is it possible without changing the direction of the main window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use [QStatusBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#addPermanentWidget).addPermanentWidget() to that effect. This is the documentation of that method:

`void QStatusBar::addPermanentWidget ( QWidget * widget, int stretch = 0 )`

> Adds the given widget permanently to this status bar, reparenting the
>   widget if it isn't already a child of this QStatusBar object. The
>   stretch parameter is used to compute a suitable size for the given
>   widget as the status bar grows and shrinks. The default stretch factor
>   is 0, i.e giving the widget a minimum of space. Permanently means that
>   the widget may not be obscured by temporary messages. **It is is located
>   at the far right of the status bar**.

Comment: Is there also an easy solution for having a permanent widget on the left side of the status bar that does not get hidden by temporary messages? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example for making a 3 part status bar, where the left part takes up 90% of the width and the two right parts take up 5% each. It also adds the sunken style that is typically used for these types of text label widgets:

```
#include <QtGui>
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *p = 0): QMainWindow(p) {
        QWidget *central = new QWidget(this);
        setCentralWidget(central);
 
        // Create multipart status bar
        m_statusLeft = new QLabel("Left", this);
        m_statusLeft->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
        m_statusMiddle = new QLabel("Middle", this);
        m_statusMiddle->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
        m_statusRight = new QLabel("Right", this);
        m_statusRight->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
        statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(m_statusLeft, 90);
        statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(m_statusMiddle, 5);
        statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(m_statusRight, 5);
    }
public slots:
private:
    QLabel * m_statusLeft;
    QLabel * m_statusMiddle;
    QLabel * m_statusRight;
};
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
 
    MainWindow m;
    m.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```